# Difficult expression of sum

Tags: summation, riemann-zeta

I wanna show that $\sum{\frac{1}{k^{4}}}=\frac{\pi^{4}}{90}$. For this, I know that
$$\sin(z)=z-\dfrac{z^{3}}{3!}+\dfrac{z^{5}}{5!}-\dfrac{z^{7}}{7!}+\cdots$$

On the other hand, also know that

$$\sin(z)=z\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left(1-\dfrac{z^{2}}{\pi^{2}k^{2}}\right)}$$
$$=z\left(1-z^{2}(\cdots)+\dfrac{z^{4}}{\pi^{4}}\left(\dfrac{1}{2^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{3^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{4^{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2^{2}3^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{2^{2}4^{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{3^{2}4^{2}}+\cdots\right)\right)$$

Therefore, I can compare the coefficients of the term $z^{5}$, i.e.,

$$\dfrac{1}{\pi^{4}}\left(\dfrac{1}{2^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{3^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{4^{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2^{2}3^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{2^{2}4^{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{3^{2}4^{2}}+\cdots\right)=\dfrac{1}{5!}$$
Then, I should prove a relation between $\left(\right)$ and $\sum{\frac{1}{k^{4}}}$

So, if define the parenthesis as $S$, then

$$S=\dfrac{1}{2^{2}}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{4^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{5^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{6^{2}}+\cdots\right)+\dfrac{1}{3^{2}}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{4^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{5^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{6^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{7^{2}}+\cdots\right)+\dfrac{1}{4^{2}}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{5^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{6^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{7^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{8^{2}}+\cdots\right)+\dfrac{1}{5^{2}}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{6^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{7^{2}}+\cdots\right)+\cdots$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2^{2}}\left(\dfrac{\pi^{2}}{6}-\dfrac{1}{2^{2}}\right)+\dfrac{1}{3^{2}}\left(\dfrac{\pi^{2}}{6}-\dfrac{1}{2^{2}}-\dfrac{1}{3^{2}}\right)+\dfrac{1}{4^{2}}\left(\dfrac{\pi^{2}}{6}-\dfrac{1}{2^{2}}-\dfrac{1}{3^{2}}-\dfrac{1}{4^{2}}\right)+\cdots$$
$$=\left(\dfrac{\pi^{4}}{36}-\dfrac{\pi^{2}}{6}\right)-\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{k^{4}}}-\left(\dfrac{1}{3^{2}2^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{4^{2}2^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{4^{2}3^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{5^{2}2^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{5^{2}3^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{5^{2}4^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{6^{2}2^{2}}+\cdots\right)$$

Because the sum $\dfrac{\pi^{2}}{6}\left(\dfrac{1}{2^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{3^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{4^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{5^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{6^{2}}+\cdots\right)$ is equal to 
$$\dfrac{\pi^{2}}{6}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{3^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{4^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{5^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{6^{2}}+\cdots-1\right)=\dfrac{\pi^{4}}{36}-\dfrac{\pi^{2}}{6}$$

Finally, How find the sum of 
$$\left(\dfrac{1}{3^{2}2^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{4^{2}2^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{4^{2}3^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{5^{2}2^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{5^{2}3^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{5^{2}4^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{6^{2}2^{2}}+\cdots\right)$$

Comment: You can try Fourier series

Comment: Well $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\pi^2/6$.  Each term you have in the parentheses is therefore $\pi^2/6$ minus a rational number.  Maybe if you write it out things will cancel.

Comment: What is $S$ supposed to represent?

Comment: Also what is the purpose of the question? To find $S$ or to find $\sum \frac{1}{k^4}$ using $S$?

Comment: @Soke Find the $\sum{\frac{1}{k^{4}}}$ using S, anyway I edited the question. Thanks!